# Routing a user to the right database during server calls

Tags: database, security, authentication, web-applications, architecture

I would like to create different environment for different teams in my web application.
To do that, I want to create a distinct database for each team (but on the same server), and to keep only one frontend environment.

Then the problem is that I need to route each user to the right database when he performs a call to the server.

How could I do that without  storing the user / db mapping in the database ?

I was thinking to put something like a client ID in the JWT token used for connection, and to name each database with this ID (Then I just need to connect to the database named by the same client ID) but it doesn't sound right.

I try to do that because I don't want to modify all my app by adding a client_id field in all tables : it's painfull and could be dangerous (A team could see data from another one if there is a bug).

The App was designed for my team, but another one in the company want to use it. I try to make it available without having to deploy one separate app each time someone want to have an access to it. 
The app should be able to know what database to use regarding the user requesting it.

Comment: For each database does the same job ? I mean each team is doing the same thing but different databases, OR, each team and databases have different data structure and stand for a different job ?

Comment: Each team does the same thing but on different databases.

Comment: So, the solution must be user based right ? It cannot be applied a request-based balancing solution. When a session is created, all db operations will be performed on one database. How about the second visit of the user ? Do you have a registration system that can identify the user for post visits ?

Comment: Yes exactly. I have a JWT token in cookie or in header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you can identify each user by an Id (JWT token in your case), just create a router table with two columns that TOKEN and DATABASE. This table will stands as your router. At the DATABASE column, use a data that identifies your teams databases such as IP, port, DB name or connection string.

When a user comes, system will request the value of the DATABASE column using the token.  If your router returns NULL, it means it is the user's first visit; assign a proper connection string to the DATABASE column of the JWT token, then use only that connection for all db operations.

Assigning the connection string can be done equally by checking the total amount of assigned databases of teams.

You can modify your ROUTER table during the registration process assigning a database to the new user.

Note that the term "router table" does not have to be a database table. You can keep this data even at RAM, or as a permanent data anywhere at disk.

Comment: Isn't that a little too expensive in read / write for the database ? (or even in RAM on a long run).
Furthermore, I should have been more accurate about the routing : It doesn't have to deal with the IP. Just the database name.

Comment: you can apply a cache mechanism to keep your router table in RAM to reduce I/O cost. Your cache data may be written to disk peridically for example per 10 minutes. You can even use a cache server such as Redis for just this purpose to keep your routing data.